# How can I show that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(x+1)}{\log{x}}=1$?

Tags: limits, logarithms

Hello I have a silly question:
How can I show that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\log(x+1)}{\log{x}}=1$.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you studied L'Hopital's rule yet?

Comment: Let $x^n=x+1$. For given values of *x*, *n* can be computed given the expression above, $\dfrac{\ln(x+1)}{\ln x}$ , whereas for known values of *n*, *x* can be written as $\sqrt[n]{1+\sqrt[n]{1+\sqrt[n]{1+\ldots}}}$ , which for $n=2$ is the [golden ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio), $\varphi=\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [l'Hospital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule):

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(x+1)}{\log(x)} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1/(x+1)}{1/x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\frac{x+1}{x}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{1 +\frac{1}{x}} = \frac{1}{1 + \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x}} = \frac{1}{1+0} = 1 $$

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is differentiable note that $f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(\xi)$ for some $\xi$ between $x$ and $x+1$ by the mean value theorem. Here $f(x)=\ln x$ and hence $0<f'(\xi)=\frac1\xi<\frac1x\to 0$.